# How can I acquire Winged Boots in DDAL without getting them in an adventure unlock?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, dnd-adventurers-league

It does not seem that [*winged boots*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/winged-boots) were included in the [Evergreen items list in the 8th season of DDAL 5e](https://www.wizardslaboratory.com/dd-adventurers-league-evergreen-magic-items-for-season-8-waterdeep-dragon-heist/). However, I saw another player in AL with the boots.

Is there any way to unlock these without getting them in an adventure unlock?

Comment: and yes, those are the item.  as a wizard I don't really need them, they are just really cool and handy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Play any session of *Ghosts of Saltmarsh*

The latest Content Catalog permits players to purchase magic items from Xendros, an NPC in the town of Saltmarsh (ALCC v8.08, p. 9):

> To purchase specific items from Magic Item Tables F or G, characters must pay gold according to the chart below and 30 downtime days for Xendros’s services, as well as the item’s cost in TCP.

**If you have 100 gp, 30 downtime days, and 16 TCP, you can purchase *winged boots*** (or any other Table F item). The ALCC isn't entirely clear when you can use this benefit, but before, during, or after a session of *Ghosts of Saltmarsh* is the most likely answer.

## DM a module that drops *winged boots* for a charity event

The evergreen DM quest *Giving DM* permits you to unlock one magic item found during a session that you run as part of a charity event. Some conventions are also run as charity events, allowing you to receive the *Giving DM* quest reward from any session you run there.

Comment: thanks, will think about it.